# How to Assert same response from list in Junit using hamcrest

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

> I want to assert if every single object contain same value eg : In the
> following code I have 20 Response Object in the list and I am expecting
> every response should have "status" is "Ok" and "message" is "success"
> in the list while testing.
> But the below code only check for the first response object in the list. How can I iterate for rest of them and check every single
> response without writing redundant code.

```
@Test
  public void testName(){
    List<Response> responseList = new ArrayList<Response>();
    Response response1 = new Response("OK","Success");  // only able to iterate this object
    Response response2= new Response("OK","Success");
    Response response3= new Response("OK","Success");
    .................................................
    Response response20 = new Response("Ok","Success");

    responseList.addAll(Arrays.asList(response1,response2,response3,....,response20));

    assertThat(responseList,Matchers.hasItems(allOf(Matchers.<Item>hasProperty("status",is("OK")),
        Matchers.<Item>hasProperty("message",is("Success")))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution : I have to check with everyItem() and it worked for me

> assertThat(items,Matchers.everyItem(allOf(Matchers.hasProperty("firstName",is("test")),
> Matchers.hasProperty("lastName",is("best")))));